# Joomla Development - Adding custom html to XML form used with 'joomla.searchtools.default'

Tags: xml, forms, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am making a backend extension for Joomla! 3.X. I have a view, where you can add, edit and delete entries. Entries are searchable. Searching is done with Joomla searchtools:

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default',array('view'> $this));
```

Form used for filtering is defined as a XML form in **/models/forms** and filtering is handled by corresponding model.

**Problem:** I would like to add descriptions to some of the numeric fields (see picture), which explain what each field does.

[image: Filters]

**I tried:**

- Adding **label** and **description** to my fields, but they do not show up (**default** does, but it is not usefull enough here, I need descriptions outside fields)
- Adding **spacer** field, but it does not show up in this context

  `<field type="spacer" name="myspacer" label="Description of field" />`
- Adding disabled text field with default value (it works, but it is not a clean solution)
- Editing search form with JavaScript located in my view (works, but is again not very clean)

**Question:** Is there a clean way to add custom HTML (such as line breaks and descriptions of fields) to my form, which is defined in a XML document?

Thank you in advance!